# Why is there only one 4-cycle in $K_{2, 2}$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I suppose an alternative title to my question is is that what makes a $4$-cycle unique? If the two vertex sets in $K_{2,2}$ are, say, $V_0 = \{a, b\}$ and $V_1 = \{c, d\}$, then how come a $4$-cycle $a-c-b-d-a$ is the same as $b-c-a-d-b$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two cycles are made up of the same set of edges.  You're traversing them in a different order, but the edge $c - b$ in $a - c - b - d - a$ is the same as the edge $b - c$ in $b - c - a - d - b$.

Comment: Ah, so the uniqueness is w.r.t. the edges?

Comment: Yes, if you're looking at undirected graphs.